# Fetching all the available microphones - Map is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to fill up a `select` with the available microphones

```
const audioInputSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');

// Updates the select element with the provided set of cameras
function updateMicrophoneList(microphones) {
    console.log(microphones);
    audioInputSelect.innerHTML = '';
    microphones.map(microphone => {
        const microphoneOption = document.createElement('option');
        microphoneOption.label = microphone.label;
        microphoneOption.value = microphone.deviceId;
    }).forEach(microphoneOption => audioInputSelect.add(microphoneOption));
}


// Fetch an array of devices of a certain type
async function getConnectedDevices(type) {
    const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    return devices.filter(device => device.kind === type)
}


// Get the initial set of cameras connected
const microphonesList = getConnectedDevices('audioinput');
updateMicrophoneList(microphonesList);

// Listen for changes to media devices and update the list accordingly
navigator.mediaDevices.addEventListener('devicechange', event => {
    const newMicrophoneList = getConnectedDevices('audioinput');
    updateMicrophoneList(newMicrophoneList);
});
```

I'm getting the error

```
VM1759 audio_devices.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: microphones.map is not a function
    at updateMicrophoneList (VM1759 audio_devices.js:7)
    at VM1759 audio_devices.js:24
```

Why doesn't `map` work here?

Comment: `getConnectedDevices` is an `async` function, so it will return a Promise. So `microphones` will be a Promise and not an array

Comment: `async` functions always return a `Promise`, so either `await` the call to `getConnectedDevices` function and then call `updateMicrophoneList` or chain a `then()` method to `getConnectedDevices` function call and call `updateMicrophoneList` function from the callback function of `then()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getConnectedDevices` is an async function, meaning that it returns a Promise instead of an array. You can use the `.then` function to update the list when the Promise is fulfilled.

```
getConnectedDevices('audioinput').then(updateMicrophoneList);
```

Comment: Thanks, just getting started with JS, so still getting used to how promises work. 

This solved it, but now I'm getting "TypeError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'HTMLSelectElement': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLOptionElement or HTMLOptGroupElement)'"